# Error "TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method"

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy

......

# Prediction
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
# round predictions
rounded = [round(x) for x in predictions]
print(rounded)

"predictions" is a list of decimals between [0,1] with sigmoid output.
```

Why does it always report this error:

```
  File "/home/abigail/workspace/ml/src/network.py", line 41, in <listcomp>
    rounded = [round(x) for x in predictions]
TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method
```

If i don't use the 'round', it prints decimals correctly. This "round" should be the Python built-in function. Why does it have anything to do with numpy?

Edited:

```
for x in predictions:
    print(x, end=' ')
```

The output is:

```
    [ 0.79361773] [ 0.10443521] [ 0.90862566] [ 0.10312044] [ 0.80714297] 
[ 0.23282401] [ 0.1730803] [ 0.55674052] [ 0.94095331] [ 0.11699325] 
[ 0.1609294]
```

Comment: I think `predictions` is a 2d array, possibly with shape (11,1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is `model`?  From what module?  It looks like `predictions` is a 2d array.  What is `predictions.shape`?  The error indicates that the `x` in `[x for x in predictions]` is an array.  It may be a single element array, but it is never the less an array.  You could try `[x.shape for x in predictions]` to see the shape of each element (row) of `predictions`.

I haven't had much occasion to use `round`, but evidently the Python function delegates the action to a `.__round__` method (much as `+` delegates to `__add__`).

```
In [932]: round?
Docstring:
round(number[, ndigits]) -> number

Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits).
This returns an int when called with one argument, otherwise the
same type as the number. ndigits may be negative.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
In [933]: x=12.34
In [934]: x.__round__?
Docstring:
Return the Integral closest to x, rounding half toward even.
When an argument is passed, work like built-in round(x, ndigits).
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
In [935]: y=12
In [936]: y.__round__?
Docstring:
Rounding an Integral returns itself.
Rounding with an ndigits argument also returns an integer.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

Python integers have a different implementation than python floats.

Python lists and strings don't have definition for this, so `round([1,2,3])` will return an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__round__'`.

Same goes for a `ndarray`.  But `numpy` has defined a `np.round` function, and a numpy array has a `.round` method.

```
In [942]: np.array([1.23,3,34.34]).round()
Out[942]: array([  1.,   3.,  34.])
In [943]: np.round(np.array([1.23,3,34.34]))
Out[943]: array([  1.,   3.,  34.])
```

`help(np.around)` gives the fullest documentation of the numpy version(s).

===================

From your last print I can reconstruct part of your `predictions` as:

```
In [955]: arr  = np.array([[ 0.79361773], [ 0.10443521], [ 0.90862566]])
In [956]: arr
Out[956]: 
array([[ 0.79361773],
       [ 0.10443521],
       [ 0.90862566]])
In [957]: for x in arr:
     ...:     print(x, end=' ')
     ...:     
[ 0.79361773] [ 0.10443521] [ 0.90862566]
```

`arr.shape` is `(3,1)` - a 2d array with 1 column.

`np.round` works fine, without needing the iteration:

```
In [958]: np.round(arr)
Out[958]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 1.]])
```

the iteration produces your error.

```
In [959]: [round(x) for x in arr]    
TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method
```

Answer (score 35):

> TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define **round** method

You tried applying round to numpy.ndarray. Apparently, this isn't supported.

Try this, use `numpy.round`:

```
rounded = [numpy.round(x) for x in predictions]
```

x is numpy array. You can also try this:

```
rounded = [round(y) for y in x for x in predictions]
```

Comment: But isn't 'round' applied to a single decimal 'x', which isn't an array?

Comment: Are you sure x is single decimal? Print it to prove it.

Comment: "predictions" is a numpy array, but 'x' is a single value.

Comment: Please see my addition.

Comment: Notice the `[` and `]`. x is numpy array which contains one element.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same error when I was trying the tutorial of [Keras](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/).

At first, I tried

```
rounded = [numpy.round(x) for x in predictions]
```

but it showed the result like this:

```
[array([1.], dtype=float32), array([0.],dtype=float32), ...]
```

then I tried this:

```
rounded = [float(numpy.round(x)) for x in predictions]
```

it showed the right outputs.

I think the "numpy.round(x)" returns list of ndarray, and contains the dtype parameter. but the outputs are correct with the value. So converting each element of the list to float type will show the right outputs as same as the tutorial.

My machine is Linux Mint 17.3(ubuntu 14.04) x64, and python interpreter is python 3.5.2, anaconda3(4.1.1), numpy 1.11.2

Comment: Can you provide some explanation please?

Comment: worked now it shows result like 1,0,0,1,1,.... instead of array([0.5168],dtype=float32)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a function that uses `Numpy` to store values. Instead of being a regular Python list, it is actually a `Numpy` array. This is generally because with machine learning, `Numpy` does a much better job at storing massive amounts of data compared to an ordinary list in Python. You can refer to the following documentation to convert to a regular list which you can then preform a comprehension:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html

Edit:

What happens if you try:

```
for x in predictions:
   for y in x.:
    print(y, end=' ')
```

Comment: 'x' is a single numerical.

Comment: Please see my addition.

Comment: @user697911 please see my comment, as numpy has a strange way of making lists of lists. This should in effect unwrap the value so that you can round.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts too. I had stored a reference to a scipy function with type `<class 'scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d'>`. This was returning a single value of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` containing a single float. I had assumed this was actually a float and it propagated back up through my library code until `round` produced the same error described above.

It was a case of debugging the call stack to check what actual type was being passed on after each function return. I then cast the return value from my original function call along the lines of `result = float(interp1d_reference(x))`. Then my code behaved as I had expected/wanted.